# How do I turn a macro into a string using cpp?

Tags: c++, string, constants, stringification

GNU's cpp allows you to turn macro *parameters* into strings like so

```
#define STR(x) #x
```

Then, `STR(hi)` is substituted with `"hi"`

But how do you turn a macro (not a macro parameter) into a string?

Say I have a macro CONSTANT with some value e.g.

```
#define CONSTANT 42
```

This doesn't work: `STR(CONSTANT)`. This yields `"CONSTANT"` which is not what we want.

Comment: I assume you want the output to be "42" -- I don't think you can without writing a function.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The trick is to define a new macro which calls `STR`.

```
#define STR(str) #str
#define STRING(str) STR(str)
```

Then `STRING(CONSTANT)` yields `"42"` as desired.

Comment: I believe an ampersand used like this is commonly referred to as the macro "stringize" operator.

Comment: That's a hash (`#`).

Answer (score 10):

You need double indirection magic:

```
#define QUOTE(x) #x
#define STR(x) QUOTE(x)

#define CONSTANT 42

const char * str = STR(CONSTANT);
```